# Парсинг текста с perl regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения, парсер

Вопрос банальный, но ответ я не него ни как не могу найти. Не могу понять как парсить данные регулярными выражениями на Perl следующего вида:

```
start
.....
load...
starting...
....
start
.....
load...
starting...
....
```

Есть ключевое слово `start` для привязки начала поиска, но концовки нету. Есть только повторяющаяся структура данных, начинающая всегда одинаково. Мои попытки написать парсер приводит к тому, что как минимум последнее структура пропадает (не попадает в парсинг):

```
(start\s).+?(\1)
(?:(start\s)).*?(?1)
```

Не получается написать регулярку, которая будет находить структуры
    start
    .....
    load...
    starting...
    ....
P.s.
не по теме, но тоже интересно. `[^a]` -исключает символ "а", а возможно ли исключить словосочетание "no"?

Comment: Добавьте язык, пример данных и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Поясните, что именно вы хотите получить на выходе. И при чём тут слово "Audut", которого нет в примере данных.

Comment: Если в вашем языке есть split, то сделайте его по выражению `/start\s/` и получите массив текстов структур

Comment: А (букво)сочетание `no` можно исключить `(?!no)`

Comment: split есть, но он относится к языку программирования.  Построчный анализ написать могу с split  и без регулярок, но хотелось бы изучить решулярные выражения.

Comment: по мимо распознавания структуры start... мне нужно от туда и значения вытащить, но это я сам как нибудь допишу. вопрос в том как выделить регулярным выражением блок от start до следующего слава start или конца документа

Comment: @ReikoReiko Вот, ключевая фраза "_от start до следующего слава start или конца документа_" прям так и пишем `(start|$)` вертикальная черта читается как ИЛИ, а $ - конец документа (при флаге s естественно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/(start\s).*?(?=\1|$)/gs
```

Тест на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ciwWhz/1)

Но лучше воспользоватся функцией `split`, если вы пишите на perl (как указали в вопросе), то выглядит это так `@arr=split(/start\s/,$data);` получили массив из структур `@arr`, с которым дальше работаем как нам удобно.

А сочетание нескольких символов можно исключить `(?!no)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let content = document.querySelector('div').innerHTML;

console.info(content.split(/\Wstart\W/).filter(e => e));
```

```html
<div>
start
.....
load...
starting...
....
start
.....
load...
starting...
....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужны тут никакие регекспы. Точнее - нужны, но как условие для split (и для дальнейшей шлифовки):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use DDP;

my $text = <<END;
start
.....
load...
starting...
....
start
.....
load...
starting...
....
END

my @rc = split( /^start\s+/m, $text );
# в map удаляем начальные и конечные пробелы из элементов
# при помощи grep удаляем пустые элементы массива
@rc = grep { $_ } map { $_ =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//s; $_ } @rc;

p @rc;
```

Вывод:

```
[
    [0] ".....
load...
starting...
....",
    [1] ".....
load...
starting...
...."
]
```